# How to fix Provider error '80020005' Type Mismatch

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-injection

For my assignment, I was given a website which I need to make secure against SQL injection. I am attempting to do so using parameters, however I am getting an error.

The original code (below) works just fine:

```
function logInUser(name,pwd) {
    var DBConn = getDBConnection();
    var SQL    = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = '" + name + "' and UserPwd = '" + pwd + "'";
    var RS     = DBConn.Execute(SQL);
    var valid  = !RS.Eof;
    if (valid) {
       Session("UserID")   = RS("UserID").value;
       Session("UserName") = RS("UserName").value;
       Session("UserFullName") = RS("UserFirstName").value + ' ' + RS("UserLastName").value;
    }
    DBConn.Close;
    return valid;
  }
```

I have attempted to modify it in this way:
function logInUser(name,pwd) {
var DBConn = getDBConnection();

```
    var uName = name;
    var uPwd = pwd;
 
    var SQL    = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = @0 and UserPwd = @1";
 
    var RS     = DBConn.Execute(SQL,uName,uPwd);
    var valid  = !RS.Eof;
    if (valid) {
       Session("UserID")   = RS("UserID").value;
       Session("UserName") = RS("UserName").value;
      Session("UserFullName") = RS("UserFirstName").value + ' ' + RS("UserLastName").value;
    }
```

When I do so I get:

> Provider error '80020005' Type Mismatch.

I have also tried modifying the statements to take one parameter, but then I get Engine error '80040e10' No value given for one or more required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:::

```
var oCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
var SQL = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserName = ? and UserPwd = ?";
oCmd.CommandText = SQL
oCmd.ActiveConnection= DBconn
var oPar = oCmd.CreateParameter("UserName ", uName);
oCmd.Parameters.Append(oPar);
var oPar2 = oCmd.CreateParameter("UserPwd", uPwd);
oCmd.Parameters.Append(oPar2);

var RS =oCmd.Execute()
```

ORIGINAL:::
Ok, I'll admit I don't know the database connection model you are looking for but I will bet you need to put your `uName` and `uPwd` into an object:

```
var credentials = {
  0: uName,
  1: uPwd
}
```

Maybe even:

```
var credentials = {
  '@0': uName,
  '@1': uPwd
}
```

possibly an array

```
var credentials = [uName, uPwd]
```

then:

```
var RS = DBConn.Execute(SQL,credentials);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it, but got an error: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: What database model is it

Comment: Actually I amended my response, try that.

Comment: I tried it, but now the whole webpage failed to load, not just when I input the credentials. I am using an Access database with an extension of .mdb

Comment: What does it say in the console? (Right-click -> Inspect Element)

Comment: On the page it says: Microsoft JScript compilation error '800a03f6'

Invalid character

/simpleCMS/library/code.inc, line 96

@0: uName,

On the console, Failed to load resource: the server responded with error 500 (internal server error)